# Why during action call inn component occurs "Actions must be plain objects." - error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

In my project I have action call, service(for http fetch requests). In action I call service and after its executing I make dispatch in order to call reducer. In my component I call this action via mapDispatchToProps. On component loading I get error and dont quite understand why

http service:

```
export class HttpService {
    static HEADERS = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Host': 'app.heavyrepair.ru',
        'User-Agent': 'myAp'
    };

    static async get(url, requestParams) {
        try {
            return await request(url,'GET', requestParams)
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('REQUEST error. GET request error text: ', e)
            throw e
        }
    }
    static async post(url, requestParams) {
        try {
            return await request(url, 'POST', requestParams)
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('REQUEST error. POST request error text: ', e)
            throw e
        }
    }
    static async delete(url, requestParams) {
        try {
            return await request(url, 'DELETE', requestParams)
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('REQUEST error. DELETE request error text: ', e)
            throw e
        }
    }
}

async function request(url, method = 'GET', requestParams) {
    const config = {
        method,
        headers: HttpService.HEADERS,
    };

    if (method === 'POST') {
        config.body = JSON.stringify(requestParams)
    }

    const response = await fetch(url, config);

    return await response.json()
}
```

action:

```
export const fetchModels = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({
        type: REQUEST_MODELS,
        payload: true,
    });

    const url = `http://localhost:8000/api/models`;

    return HttpService.get(url)
        .then(response => {
            dispatch({
                type: REQUEST_MODELS,
                payload: false,
            });
            dispatch({
                type: RECEIVE_MODELS,
                payload: response,
            });
        });
};
```

and call action in component did mount:

```
class MainPage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchModels()
            .then(this.setState({loading: false}));
    }

    render() {
        const {
            models,
            modelsLoading
        } = this.props;

        return (
            <div className="block-model-list">
             ...
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => (
    {
        fetchModels: () => dispatch(fetchModels()),
    }
);


const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        models        : state.models,
        modelsLoading : state.modelsLoading,
    }
};

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MainPage));
```

error `redux-logger.js?5d82:1 Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.` happens in didmount on action call. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actions in redux should be plain JavaScript objects. However by doing `fetchModels: () => dispatch(fetchModels())` you are dispatching the result of `fetchModels()` function execution as an action.

In order to perform asynchronous operations inside the action creator, custom middleware has to be used. One such popularly used middleware is [Redux Thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) . It will let you write async action creators.